# C++: g++ compiler: clash of stdio with virtual functions?

Tags: c++, windows, g++, cygwin, virtual

I am not able to use stdio combined with virtual functions (Windows Vista, Cygwin, GCC 4.8.2)

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A
{
    public:

    //  If I make g() as virtual, stdio doesn't print.
    virtual void g() {}
};

int main()
{
    A a; // Or I could remove this object to make stdio print.
    printf("testing\n");
}
```

With hint by "Borgleader", I found that it works when used with "-O2" option. Linking seems to be different when used with/without "-O2".

```
/home/user> g++ test.cc
/home/user> ./a.exe
/home/user> ldd ./a.exe
    ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/ntdll.dll (0x77540000)
    kernel32.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/kernel32.dll (0x75790000)
    cygwin1.dll => /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll (0x61000000)
    cyggcc_s-1.dll => /usr/bin/cyggcc_s-1.dll (0x6bf40000)
    cygstdc++-6.dll => /usr/bin/cygstdc++-6.dll (0x6c480000)

/home/user> g++ -O2 test.cc
/home/user> ./a.exe
testing
/home/user> ldd ./a.exe
    ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/ntdll.dll (0x77540000)
    kernel32.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/kernel32.dll (0x75790000)
    cygwin1.dll => /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll (0x61000000)
```

Thanks for selbie's suggestion to try GDB. Now things are a bit more clear. I should forget about printf, the program doesn't even load! With option "-O2", it works ok (even in GDB).

```
/home/user> g++ -g test.cc
/home/user> gdb ./a.exe
<<Edited for brevity>>
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40119e: file test.cc, line 14.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/user/a.exe
[New Thread 4888.0x13e0]
gdb: unknown target exception 0xc0000139 at 0x77549cfc
During startup program exited with code 0xc0000139.
```

Another hint that the program was not loading is that, even if I put sleep(100) in it, it exists immediately.

---

**Summary**: The problem got solved after updating the entire cygwin installation

**Details**: Reinstall of just g++ compiler did not help. Updating just g++ compiler to new version did not help. Updating the entire Development category did not help. Updating Base category did not help. Updating the entire cygwin installation helped. It remains unknown as per why the previous install was still working with "-O2" option. I could have continued to use "-O2" option. But, I chose to do complete update of cygwin.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34716fadf2c93e04), and there no reason I know of that would explain why virtual functions would have this effect.

Comment: I saw your command line compilation. I think you can reproduce the problem if you exclude the "-O2" from your compilation.

Comment: No, it still prints testing even without the -O2 flag.

Comment: For me this prints: g++ -O2 test.cc && ./a.exe. This doesn't: g++ test.cc && ./a.exe. Must be some quirk in linking of libraries of my installation. Tx for your help.

Comment: @user3196458 - Since this is a bit of a mystery, could you compile with the "-g" flag for both the working an non working version.  Then "gdb a.exe" followed by "disassemble main" for both compiles?  Bonus points if you actually "stepi" through your code to see if printf is getting called.

Comment: May I suggest using `iostream` rather than `stdio`?

Comment: @Cramer - There are plenty of ways to hide the bug. None of which will tell the OP why his program, that should work as expected, is not.

Comment: I just upgraded my CygWin install.  Still no repro.

Comment: @Cramer - The original failure occurred when using iostreams. Then I made a minimal test case by using stdio.

Comment: @selbie - I guess I will have to upgrade my cygwin (and destroy the evidence of this bug).

Comment: Did you try "disassemble main"? I suspect that the stack is somehow getting corrupted. The introduction of a virtual method on class A, makes sizeof(a) on the stack grow an extra 4 bytes. But in the end, we're very likely to see that this is a result of a "dirty machine". If re-installing Cygwin fixes the problem, was there ever a real bug in the first place? :)

Comment: @selbie - unfortunately there is nothing to disassemble. It fails before reaching user written code. Is there a way to dump code of main without running the program?

Comment: @selbie - I ran "info functions". It gave me 16 functions (3 in user code, rest in cygwin). I put a break on all of them. The gdb failed b4 entering any of them.

Comment: I think typing "gdb a.exe" and then "disassemble main" should suffice. I'm starting to think re-installing Cygwin might be the best option. :(

Comment: @selbie - Damn. You are so right! I am kicking myself that I had known that I could disassemble without running the program. A great opportunity of having fun is lost :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was to update and reinstall (erase & download) many times Cygwin, but at the end it turned out that I had to downgrade my g++ compiler from 5.2 to 4.9. I suppose that this has something to do with a specific version of Cygwin C++ runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in this code that should not work.

You can switch to VirtualBox and run gcc on Linux VM, this will be more robust than cygwin and other .exe stuff which is modelling Linux on Windows.

Seems that now you are testing cygwin implementation of compiler.