# Adding std::cout to global operator new masks SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, new-operator, coredump

This question is part of my exercise in learning about overriding global operator new. I need to ask the community for help understanding runtime behavior, because I'm at a loss trying to understand this.

**This code intentionally produces memory leaks and a SIGSEGV**

**The Code**

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <new>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

namespace ns
{

class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo()
        {
            std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        }

        virtual ~Foo()
        {
            if (!mSet.empty()) { std::cout << "You have unfreed heap allocations!" << std::endl; }
            else { std::cout << "Good job! No unfreed heap allocations!" << std::endl; }
        }

        void Add(void* p) { mSet.insert(p); }

        void Delete(void* p) { mSet.erase(p); }

    protected:
        std::set< void*, std::less<void*> > mSet;
};

Foo gFoo;

}

void* operator new(size_t size)
{
//    std::cout << "In overridden operator new!" << std::endl;
    void* p = malloc(size);
    ns::gFoo.Add(p);
    return p;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int* p1 = new int(5);
    int* p2 = new int(6);

    return 0;
}
```

**Compilation and Error**

Note: environment is Cywin, therefore `a.exe` instead of `a.out` below.

```
>g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 5.4.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
>g++ -std=c++14 -g main.cpp
>
>./a.exe
ns::Foo::Foo()
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
>
```

This error is expected: note that the overridden `operator new` eventually calls std::set::insert(...), which itself uses `new` leading to infinite recursion.

**The "Fix"**

Uncomment the `std::cout` line in `operator new(size_t)`.

Compiling and running with this change results in a stream of `cout`s to the console, as expected, but no "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" message anywhere, and no .stackdump file.

This makes no sense to me.

I *do not* believe that introducing the `std::cout` fixes the problem, but neither can I explain why it seems to be masking it.

Desperate to understand what's at play here. Thank you for any insight.

(*Just to reiterate, the memory leak and infinite recursion are intentional for the purpose of this question. This issue arose incidentally to more proper code I was working on, and the code is just a MCV example to demonstrate the issue.*)

**Update**

On a true Linux box, the program SIGSEGVs with both versions of the code, i.e. with and without the `std::cout`. This at least helps me reclaim some sanity, as this conforms to expectation.

**Update**

I'm going to stop actively investigating this topic since it was, to begin with, just an incidental discovery while I was working towards something else, and also because the code behaves as expected - i.e. SIGSEGVs both with and without the `std::cout` - on a true Linux box. I will leave the question open, though, in case someone can eventually offer a definitive answer. It's still slightly concerning that this issue manifests at all, because it means Cygwin "masks" the reliable presentation of errors under certain circumstances.

Comment: Did you program end eventually?

Comment: @fefe: Yes, the program does end eventually. Analyzing the terminal output of the "fixed" version, gives every indication of ending gracefully.

Comment: Can not reproduce in Ubuntu. I get a SIGSEGV in either way.

Comment: @fefe: Maybe that's a good thing. Maybe this is some odd platform-dependent behavior. My dev environment is cygwin, so it's Windows under the hood, so maybe there's some odd quirk that causes this inconsistent behavior on Windows...? I'll continue to wait and see if anyone else can reproduce and/or offer a conclusive answer.

Comment: @StoneThrow, deleted my previous comment since it is not relevant.

Comment: Tried your code, it gets segment fault anyway with or without the `std::cout` line in `operator new()`, on gcc 5.4.0, Ubuntu 16.04. The segment fault is caused by recursion of `std::insert()` and `operator new()`

Comment: It is just undefined behaviour. And that is what you observe.

Comment: @WhozCraig Your callstack shows infinite recursion, which eventually results in a SIGSEGV, which I noted in the OP was intentional and expected. I'm trying to figure out why introducing the `std::cout` hides the infinite recursion+SIGSEGV and results in what looks like graceful completion.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Cygwin x64. Getting a SIGSEGV either way.

Comment: I'm starting to think this may not have been a good question. It looks like I've just uncovered some quirk of Cygwin rather anything fundamental. The inconsistencies in observations is no help either. We have 2 Cygwin users on this post (myself and @BlackPen) who can reproduce the problem, yet you cannot. I'll leave this open for a bit more in case there's a definitive answer, but if not, @MSalters' is the closest to a conclusion.

Comment: *"Undefined behavior means anything can happen including but not limited to the program giving your expected output. But never rely on the output of a program that has UB. The program may just crash."* Also see [Consistency of undefined behavior for a given compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74155360/consistency-of-undefined-behavior-for-a-fixed-compiler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a reasonable guess why `std::cout` affects the observed results: it is by far the most complex call. With a possible synchronization with `printf`, replaced streambufs, etcetera, it can block inlining.

Inlining is a problem for recursive functions, of course, because it would cause a stack overflow in a naive compiler. But a decent compiler can turn that recursive function into an iterative one, and this may affect the visible symptoms of a stack overflow. Your example obviously still is going to run out of memory, but that could now be heap memory instead of stack memory.

Comment: What you say sounds close to an answer. Just a couple questions before I flag yours as _the_ answer: not sure I understand why inlining is a problem for recursive functions. Isn't inlining just replacing a function's body in place of where the function is called? I.e. wouldn't stack use be equivalent either way? If I understood you: you're saying with no `cout`, `operator new` could be inlined. but with the `cout`, `operator new` could be no longer inlined? Are you saying that heap use by `cout` causes out-of-heap before stack overflow? If so, is there no SIGSEGV or equivalent triggered?

Comment: He's compiling in `-O0` mode (default). In that mode GCC does not inline anything anyway.

Comment: @StoneThrow: "Inlining is just replacing" is the naive view that I was referring to. That doesn't work with a recursive function: If `f(x)` calls `f(x-1)`, you can't insert the body of `f` into itself! But a smart compiler can do something else: it can often insert a `goto` back to the begin of the function. This *does* affect the way in which the stack is used, because you no longer need to store return addresses.

Comment: @MSalters: I see. I'd always thought that inlining _was_ just function-body replacement, almost like preprocessor macro replacement. Thanks for teaching me something new.

Comment: @MSalters: Are you saying, though, that without the `std::cout`, the compiler could have tried to inline my `operator new`? I thought one needed to explicitly use the keyword inline to allow the compiler to do this. Moreover, even without `std::cout`, my `operator new` was doing a `std::set::insert()` which also seems "complex" enough to have blocked inlining, no? (If this discussion is getting long in the tooth, no need to respond, no worries)

Comment: @StoneThrow: `inline` is a hint, and modern compilers don't actually need hints. (The keyword also sidesteps the One Definition Rule, which increases the chance of successful inlining).

Comment: @MSalters: I'm still just a bit skeptical that `std::cout` would have affected inlining, while `std::set::insert()` would not have; they both seem "complex" enough to have blocked inlining. But at the same time, I do sorta kinda get what you've been explaining, and you've taught me a thing or two, so I think this deserves an answer vote. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The code **should** get segment fault anyway with or without `std::cout` line in your `operator new()`, because it should gets recursive calls of `std::set::insert()` and `operator new()` and eventually gets stack overflow.

1. Your `operator new` calls `ns::gFoo.Add(p)`
2. `Foo::Add()` calls `std::set::insert()`
3. `insert()` will allocate new memory and calls `operator new()`
4. Now it gets recursion.

But you're indicating that removing `std::cout` fixes the problem.

So I would guess that in your environment, `std::std::insert()` does not dynamically allocate memory for small objects or for small size, then it does not call `operator new()` so avoids the recursion.

While `std::cout << "In overridden operator new!"` will allocate memory, so it calls `operator new()` and gets recursion.

Anyway, you can use `gdb` to debug the segment fault, see the call stack and find the recursion as the root cause.

Comment: std::set::insert() does dynamically allocate memory regardless of size of objects being allocated (theoretically this must be true, but also verified with gdb). "While `std::cout << "In overridden operator new!" will allocate memory so it calls operator new() and gets recursion" -- but this should therefore also result in SIGSEGV. "The code **should** get segment fault anyway with out without `std::cout`" - I agree with this, so I'm trying to reconcile practice does not match theory. I suspect it is because of Cygwin/Windows. I will be able to verify on a *nix box in a few hours.

Comment: Yes, what I said "in your environment", I mean your Cygwin/Windows environment which I'm not familiar with, so it's just a guess, either `std::set::insert()` does not allocates, or it allocates without using `operator new()`?

Answer (score 0):

I have cygwin. I created a minimized test and confirmed OP's results.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
#include <set>
#include <memory>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

std::set< void*, std::less<void*> > mSet;
unsigned long long counter=0;

void* operator new(size_t size)
{
    counter++;
    printf("counter: %d\n",counter);
    void* p = malloc(size);
    mSet.insert(p);
    return p;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int* p1 = new int(5);
    std::cerr << "Exiting=" << counter << std::endl;
}
```

With printf commented out, it gave SIGSEGV in few seconds as follows:

```
~> ./a.exe
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./a.exe
```

With printf present, the counter goes upto 4811, doesn't get SIGSEGV, but exits silently without reaching end of main, as follows. When I optimize it with -O3, the same thing happens (but now at counter value of 64936). With -O0 also, the counter went upto 4811.

```
zsh-user> ./a.exe
....
```

With printf present, and output redirected, it gave SIGSEGV as follows. Optimization levels didn't change behaviour of this test.

```
~> ./a.exe > out
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./a.exe > out
```

I don't have an explanation (I was planning on debugging it next). I had [a simillar strange problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22139323/c-g-compiler-clash-of-stdio-with-virtual-functions), 2 years ago (where nobody else on other platforms were able to reproduce it; only one other cygwin user was able to reproduce it; that problem disappeared with a complete reinstall of cygwin).

Comment: Not sure who downvoted, but I'm +1ing because it is useful to know that the issue is reproducible by someone else, especially since there is another Cygwin user (RustyX) who was not able to repro the issue.

Comment: @StoneThrow, I edited my post to add few clarifications. I will try debugging it further tomorrow if I get some time.

Comment: No need to debug further unless you're really curious. The fact that the code behaves "as expected" on a true linux box (i.e. SIGSEGVs both with and without `std::cout` is probably enough for me to acknowledge this is a quirk of Cygwin. This is a bit worrying, though, since my Cygwin PC is where I write up quick snippets of test code, so it's concerning if it can't be trusted to expose errors in an expected, reliable manner. I'll leave this question open in case anyone can come up with a conclusive answer.