# Can static_cast gives nullpt for non-nullptr argument?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, static-cast, null-pointer

The following code [gives me a warning](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jyTDSp0XbnL0FY4n) "null pointer dereference" despite checking the pointer value before casting:

```
struct ID { virtual ~ID() = default; };
struct IF { virtual void g() = 0; };
struct F : IF { void g() {} };
struct D : ID, F { };

int main() {
    D* d;
    if (d) static_cast<IF*>(d)->g();
}
```

Is it based on using uninitialized pointer value with `-O2` optimization mode or `static_cast` really can result in null pointer value for non-null argument (e.g. when multiple inheritance is in action)?

Comment: `d` is uninitialized so dereferencing it is undefined behavior. See [Where exactly does C++ standard say dereferencing an uninitialized pointer is undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285895/where-exactly-does-c-standard-say-dereferencing-an-uninitialized-pointer-is-un). *"Undefined behavior means anything can happen including but not limited to the program giving your expected output. But never rely(or make conclusions based up) on the output of a program that has UB."*

Comment: Also [Consistency of undefined behavior for a fixed compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74155360/consistency-of-undefined-behavior-for-a-fixed-compiler/74166343#74166343)

Comment: Change `D* d;` to `D* d{};` to get rid of the undefined behavior, and to get the behavior (I presume) being attempted.

Comment: For polymorphic cast use dynamic_cast unless you are totally sure you're dealing with a derived instance (which in my designs is never, since I don't want to rely on that)

Comment: The undefined behavior here is for actually already reading the indeterminate value of the uninitialized `d` in `if(d)`. The compiler is not required to assume that the value read in `if(d)` is consistent with the value used in `static_cast<IF*>(d)` because it is indeterminate. So in that sense the warning message isn't incorrect. However it should really warn about the read of the uninitialized value.