# Why am I getting consistent content on the stack if there is no code initializing it?

Tags: c++, gcc, memory, x86

I have an unusual task of figuring out if a piece of code using uninitialized variables has a consistent behavior or not. The analysis of the disassembly suggests that it should be indeterminate, since the location on the stack where those variables are stored is never written to. However when I run the code and dump the stack, I always see repeating values and consistency in which bytes change and which stay the same.

The piece of code I'm working on is a dynamic ELF library. The executable loads the library and starts a specific function in a thread. This is where I might be wrong but to my understanding, when the thread is created, the operating system pulls some random part of the physical RAM and allocates it as the stack for the thread - so the thread should start with random garbage pulled from anything that previously run on the system. But some of the variables I'm testing will get consistent values every time I run the program. Similarly, every fourth word of the stack has the value 0000 and there are repeating byte sequences that change value every test but always appear at the same location in memory.

I know for a fact that, inside of the thread, the stack pointer never reaches the uninitialized variables. I checked every callq I could find before the function in which the variables are defined, none of them ever get any deeper than few bytes and return. The variables are around 0x1000 bytes deep inside the stack of the function defining them.

I doubt anyone can give me the actual answer as to why this is happening without seeing the code but an explanation how this is even possible would still be very appreciated, since at this moment, I'm completely dumbfounded.

Comment: The kernel zeros fresh memory pages to avoid leaking data between processes, between users, or from kernel data to user-space.  The linked duplicate goes into more details; IIRC I wrote my answer there to cover questions like this.  It's pretty normal for stack memory to be the same every run of a program (for an identical build on the same system with the same startup code), at least early in the program's execution before any input-dependent function calls have been made or not.

Comment: The reason this is happening is because this is what happens when you get [demons flying out of everyone's noses](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) they tend to fly in the same direction. But it means absolutely nothing, and probably has something to do with some low level details of how your operating system works, which can change at any time, when updates get installed.

Comment: *using uninitialized variables has a consistent behavior or not.* I doubt *consistent behavior* is applicable to undefined behavior.

Comment: Recommended reading: [Undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) (and *do read* all the very nice linked articles at the end, they provide very valuable information that's relevant to your question).

Comment: _dynamic ELF library_ Timely

Comment: [Consistency of undefined behavior for a fixed compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74155360/consistency-of-undefined-behavior-for-a-fixed-compiler)